# Ch. in Organ score

Tags: rehearsal

Christmas musical has organ accomp, and there's a Ch. near the top of the score a couple pages in. Was asked if I knew the meaning...and I don't. Any help here? Thanks.

Comment: Related question: [What does Grt. and Sw. mean in this organ score?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24426/what-does-grt-and-sw-mean-in-this-organ-score)

Answer (score 2):

When an organ has two manuals they are usually called Great (Gt.) and Swell (Sw.)  A third manual may be called Choir (Ch.).  "The Choir organ contains stops well suited for accompaniment or light solo work, especially when working with the vocal choir."